# Dropping variables grouped if statement and creating time to event variable in R

Tags: r

I am trying to work with a big dataset and started using R for such purpose. I am trying to create a variable named time to diagnosis (time_to_dx) which is a time to event variable (yearHb - Dx) but for each patient ID. I would also like to drop all those measurements done prior the diagnosis but i am guessing once I am able to create the time_to_dx variable, that should be straightforward.
I am attaching an example of the dataset and the expected outcome.
Many thanks for your help.

| ID | Dx | Hb | yearHb | *time_to_dx* |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2001 | 16.5 | 1997 |  |
| 1 | 2001 | 21.3 | 2002 | 1 |
| 1 | 2001 | 19.5 | 2005 | 4 |
| 2 | 2005 | 14.5 | 2002 |  |
| 2 | 2005 | 15.6 | 2004 |  |
| 2 | 2005 | 21 | 2006 | 1 |
| 2 | 2005 | 22 | 2007 | 2 |
| 2 | 2005 | 17.9 | 2003 |  |
| 3 | 2006 | 18.1 | 2003 |  |
| 3 | 2006 | 19.7 | 2006 | 0 |
| 3 | 2006 | 19.1 | 2008 | 2 |
| 3 | 2006 | 17.3 | 2007 | 1 |

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `dt` is the name of your data.frame

Using `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)
result <- dt %>% 
  mutate(
    time_to_dx = yearHb - Dx,
    time_to_dx = ifelse(time_to_dx < 0, NA, time_to_dx)
    )
```

Using base R:

```
dt$time_to_dx = dt$yearHb - dt$Dx
dt$time_to_dx = ifelse(dt$time_to_dx  < 0, NA, dt$time_to_dx )
```